# Custom System Tray Notification Qt

Tags: c++, qt, notifications, system-tray

I'm searching from 3 days ago how to make a custom system tray message using Qt.
I guess I'll have to make a class which extend from the balloon class but, how ?

I want to make something like that :

[image: example]
<sub>(source: [elance.com](https://ws.elance.com/file/custom_tray_popup.png?crypted=Y3R4JTNEcG9ydGZvbGlvJTI2ZmlkJTNEODk1MzI4OTYlMjZyaWQlM0QtMSUyNnBpZCUzRDI5NzM3MDQ=))</sub>

Or also like the Skype Notification zone :

[image: other example]

Thanks for your future answers !

Answer (score 1):

You can use QSystemTrayIcon, show the message via the method showMessage()

Check this vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fe1L6u064ao
Although the guy speaks spanish I guess you can still follow how to do it (I could :-))

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QxtToolTip](http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/0.6/qxttooltip.html) class in [Qxt](http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/wiki/Home). It enables you to show any arbitrary widget as a tooltip. So i think you can create your custom widget and show it using `QxtToolTip` in the proper position. You can use this static function :

```
void QxtToolTip::show ( const QPoint & pos, QWidget * tooltip, QWidget * parent = 0, const QRect & rect = QRect() )   [static]
```

It can be like:

```
#include <QxtToolTip>

MyCustomWidget widget;
QPoint myPosition(x,y);
QxtToolTip::show ( &myPosition, &widget, parent);
```

Comment: Seems that `libqxt` is no longer maintained. Any alternatives?